# NSManagedObject ignoring changed transformable

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, magicalrecord

I have a very basic caching system for some objects that conform to NSCoding.  A method takes the object, extracts some information for keys and search parameters, creates or updates an NSManagedObject, and saves it to the persistent store:

[image: CoreData model for SECachedQuestion]

```
+ (void)updateQuestion:(StacManQuestion *)question site:(StacManSite *)site
{
    // 1. Look up with a basic predicate.
    SECachedQuestion *cachedQuestion = [SECachedQuestion 
        findFirstWithQuestionId:question.questionId site:site];

    // 2. Create if missing.
    if (!cachedQuestion) {
        cachedQuestion = [SECachedQuestion MR_createEntity];
        cachedQuestion.questionId = question.questionId;
        cachedQuestion.site = site.apiSiteParameter;
    }

    // 3. Update properties.
    cachedQuestion.isFavorite = question.favorited;
    cachedQuestion.lastAccessTime = [NSDate date];
    cachedQuestion.question = question;

    // 4. Save
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] 
        MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        /* ... */
    }];
}
```

The first time this code runs, it works perfectly.  The object gets saved to the cache and is instantly available for the next run.  After that, however, assigning a new value to `cachedQuestion.question` does nothing.

I've added some breakpoints and found the following:

1. The assignment to question does not update `changedValues`:

   > ```
   > (lldb) po [cachedQuestion changedValues]  {
   >     lastAccessTime = "2014-07-16 17:16:45 +0000";
   > }
   > ```
2. `question` and `cachedQuestion.question` start out with the different addresses and then end with the same so an assignment is definitely occurring.
3. If I put a step before the assignment that sets `cachedQuestion.question = nil`, I get the following, but the the record for question disappears again on reassignment.

   > ```
   > (lldb) po [cachedQuestion changedValues]  {
   >     lastAccessTime = "2014-07-16 17:16:45 +0000";
   >     question = "<null>";
   > }
   > ```
4. <s>Here's another super up thing.  I went ahead and did a test where I just set `cachedQuestion.question = nil` for a few builds of the app.  This is working fine for subsequent lookups in a single run, but every time when the app launches the first read of cachedQuestion.question goes back to the original value!  I can confirm that new cached questions are begin created *and* lastAccessTime has no problem updating.  It's just this one field that is frozen in time.</s>  *This was because of data validation.  `nil` got it to show up in changed values but save failed as it was not optional.*

**UPDATE**

Right now I'm doing a sad sad hack where any time there is a change I delete the old record and insert a new one.  It works well enough but I'd much rather know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're not writing your changes to the correct context. First, stop using contextForCurrentThread. It's deprecated and will cause you a crash 1 time out of 100, which is one too many. You also risk crashing since this method **can and will** return a context that is not the default context. Making managed object assignments across contexts will also crash, for good reason.

Instead, you should explicitly create your context, write your changes to it, and then save it at the end of your method. That will likely solve the majority of the problems you're seeing.

Comment: I'm not seeing any change here.  All the calls in this flow were originally happening on the main thread so there was no risk of the thread disappearing during the save.  The failure point still appears to be that I set a new value for question but changedValues doesn't update.

Comment: contextForCurrentThread is (or will eventually be) your problem, bottom line. Stop using it. If you're doing it all on the main thread for now (yuck) then be explicit and try your stuff with the default context.

Answer (score 0):

I had to read this several times...
I think the problem here is that you do not use relationships correctly.
NSManagedObjects should be set up as an Entity.

It should not be Transformable but a relationship to an entity.

From the context you can get the first all objects in the first entity in a MutableArray, then get all of its related objects in a new MutableArray of objects through its relationship by calling this when one object is selected:

self.newArray = [[self.oldObject.relationshipName allObjects]mutableCopy];

You will then only get content related to selected object and not all objects in the related entity.

This means there should not be a question attribute but a relationship to the entity question.